# Add BIDS to free SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed the free version of SQL Server 2008 (without SPs) and I am looking for a way to add Business Intelligence Development System (BIDS). Can this be done or do I need to install a different free version? I am just trying to learn about SSIS, SSRS and SSAS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need SQL Server Express with Advanced Services which I believe includes BIDS (a limited version). You can [find it here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1842).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am assuming that I must uninstall SQL Server 2008 before attempting to install SQL Server Express with Advanced Services. What fun!!

Comment: Not if they're both the express edition (and I assume that's what you have because you said 'free version'). You should just be able to fire up the installer for the Advanced Services version and install only the bits you want. One thing to note: There are two versions of SQL Server with 2008 in the title - SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008R2. They are NOT the same product and have differing product version numbers: 2008 = 10, 2008RS = 10.5. They are not interchangeable so make sure you get the right installer (although I have a feeling that BIDS is the same version in both).